# REGEX to discard floating numbers and leading zeros

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have a Regex expression which should allow only positive number except zero and floating numbers `^0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*$` but it is allowing floating numbers, can anyone modify this and let me know the regex

valid:

```
1-any number 
01 - any number
```

not valid:

```
00 - any leading zeros
0
1.4 - floating numbers
abc - alphabets 
-1 - negative numbers
```

Comment: You can try this: `^[0-9]\d*$`

Comment: Is there anything wrong with  `[1-9][0-9]*`

Comment: If you don't want floating numbers, why is your expression allowing decimal point? I guess my question is, is it "should allow only (positive number except zero) and floating numbers" or "should allow only positive number except (zero and floating numbers)"?

Comment: Hi Andres, It should allow only positive number except (zero and floating numbers)

Comment: Hi Rahul ^[0-9]\d*$ allows zero which i dont want

Comment: Hi Wallace, your expression still allows floating numbers

Comment: No, really it doesn't.  There's no decimal point in the expression I suggested.

Comment: @DavidWallace seems, he's talking about javascript and it curiously accepts floating values for this pattern if not start and end of the string are determined

Comment: Even with the `^` and `$`?  If that's true, then that would be a browser bug, not a language feature.

Comment: @DavidWallace no, I mean, it's ok with ^ and $ in javascript, but without it, it accepts float values too. Just in javascript, java doesn't need it

Comment: Ah, I think  you edited your comment after I replied to it.  Sure.  So it's not actually matching floating values - it's a question of whether the OP uses it to match the whole string, or only part of the string.  Of course a floating value is going to have a "part" that matches integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stanislav's regex (see below) I think matches what you want. Upvote him if you agree! (Note: you may need to wrap it in ^ and $ so it matches the beginning and end of the string, like this: `^[0]*[1-9][0-9]*$`)
You can test it here:

```css
/* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Data_form_validation */
input:invalid {
  border: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<input pattern="[0]*[1-9][0-9]*">
```

Comment: 01 - any number should be valid too

Comment: Hi Stanislav, I tried your regex in http://tools.netshiftmedia.com/regexlibrary/, you can see it still accepts 1.4, 2.1, wherein i dont want to accept the floating numbers. actually its a requirement to enter the number of quantity.. so quantity should not be like floating, alphabet, negative, or 000, 00 etc

Comment: Throw a ^ and $ around it (to match start and end of string) and it should work!
^[0]*[1-9][0-9]*$

Comment: @user3436400 java regex does not accept the floating values for this pattern. If you are not using java, but javascript, you have to add a ^ and $ to it to determine start and end of the string

Comment: Hey, Thanks Stanislav and Fievel, this worked !! and yes i was using javascript. Thanks again.

Comment: @user3436400 if it's worked you can accept the answer, this could help someone in the future to find it

Comment: Hi Stanislav, could you please let me know how to accept the answer? i have allready clicked the up arrow on the left corner.

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern `[0]*[1-9][0-9]*` as:

```
String str = "00012";
str.matches("[0]*[1-9][0-9]*");
```

Where:

`[0]*` is any number of 0 at start of the string

`[1-9]` one digit from 1 to 9

and `[0-9]*` any number of digits from 0 to 9

If you want to use it with JavaScript, just modify it with ^ and $ to determine the start and the end of the string like:

```
^[0]*[1-9][0-9]*$
```